# Pinned tab sets Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-navigation

Does anyone know of any plugins or extensions for VS 2012 that allow you to create pinned tab sets/groups? By this I mean a way of assigning a number of tabs/files to a group (think grouping units in an RTS game) and preferably then being able to switch between groups using shortcut keys (ctrl+1, ctrl+2 etc).

I think this would be really useful to allow you easily open up groups of related files, for example the view model, controller, view, tests and associated scripts.

The pinning feature does go some way towards helping this goal but only for one set, not many.

It would also be really useful to do this for related projects in a large solution in order to speed up build times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sam,

You can partially get this functionality with the [Favorite Documents](http://www.svprogramming.net/favorite-documents/index.html) extension (developed by me). At least assigning files to a group and opening this group later.

Comment: Almost, close enough. Thanks.